# Trying to pull image from private-repo.microsoft.com

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm looking to pull an image off of http://private-repo.microsoft.com

- Ubuntu: 16.04
- Docker: 1.12.3-rc1

I've tried.

`docker login https://private-repo.microsoft.com` with username and password and get a `Login Succeeded`

`docker pull private-repo.microsoft.com/<imagename>:main` and I get `unauthorized: authenication required`

I've tried tweaking the `~/.docker/config.json` file with email tag.

I've tried dropping the `.pem` file in the `/etc/ssl/certs` directory.

I'm out of ideas... please help... =(

Answer (score 0):

The repo shows this error also when it doesn't find the image. Be sure your image is spelled right. For example I see **main** at the end when usually a **latest** should be there:

```
docker pull private-repo.microsoft.com/<imagename>:latest
```

Regards

Comment: is there any way to differentiate? verify somehow that the image exists?

Comment: You can check the Docker Registry API. In your browser enter: https:// private-repo.microsoft.com/v2 and the command. Check for Docker Registry API on docker documentation site. I don't remember right now the command